# Clickable image footer, html

Tags: html, css, image, footer

I have a 2000*300px image I am planning to use as a footer. There are four sections in the middle, and each needs to be clickable - they should be links. I'm using an image map right now.

I have a footer  at the bottom of the site. It has a width of 100% and a height of 300px. What I need to do is centre the image in the middle of the div, with any overflow hidden.
It must remain clickable - that's why I can't just resize the image.

So!

- How can I centre the element within the footer div, with overflow hidden?
- Alternatively, how can I dynamically resize the footer image but still have it clickable?
- Alternatively, how can I implement the same effect - a continuous-appearing image with clickable sections as a footer?

Comment: Please give us an example to work with at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/x4Mbr/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is ok to allow the image to be cut off on the sides, then you can center the image by setting the image position to center in the CSS.

```
.footer {background: transparent url(path/to/image) no-repeat bottom center;}
```

To get the have other clickable elements just nest new divs or paragraphs or links in footer div.

It would look something like this.

```
<div class="footer">
    <a>Clickable Content</a>
    <a>Clickable Content</a>
    <a>Clickable Content</a>
    <a>Clickable Content</a>
</div>
```

Then you can set the height and width for each of those. Then set the link. Or use divs and set the links inside of them.

```
.footer a {height: 300px; width: 25%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

***CSS CODE***

```
    .footer {background: transparent url(path/to/image) no-repeat bottom center;}
```

*HTML CODE*

```
    <div class="footer">
        <a>Clickable Content</a>
        <a>Clickable Content</a>
        <a>Clickable Content</a>
        <a>Clickable Content</a>
    </div>
```

Also can use this:

```
    .footer a {height: 300px; width: 25%;}
```

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself.